# Recording audio from the microphone in Windows Phone 7 Series

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm wondering if anyone has any code samples or links to documentation that demonstrate how to capture audio from the device's microphone on the new Windows Phone Series 7. I've recently downloaded the Windows Phone SDK CTP for Visual Studio 2010 and I'm struggling to find any supporting documentation that might help.

Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone.Start, Stop and GetData.  don't know if it works but know that's where the mic is.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [blog post](http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/recording-audio-in-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7/) for an example on how to do it.  It's not as straight forward as just using the XNA Microphone class.  There are a couple of other things you need to do.